# Counting number of occurrences in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm learning R and I face a problem I don't know how to solve. I have an input subset similar to the following, with a client_id and 7 integers:

```
(client_id, 10, 8, -5, 8, 1, -23, 12)
```

I would like return the same vector but with an additional fields. First, one containing the number of times any of the other values are negative. For the above example, the result would be:

```
(client_id, 10, 8, -5, 8, 1, -23, 12, 2)
```

because there are just 2 negative numbers in the 7 integers.

A second field would be the number of values that are 0

```
(client_id, 10, 8, -5, 8, 1, -23, 12, 2, 3)
```

because there are 3 values between 0 and 10.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `client_id` a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vector is `x` it would be

```
x <- c(x, length(which(x[-1]<0)), length(which(x[-1]>=0 & x[-1]<=10)))
```

To answer to @Nishanth : you can also do

```
x <- c(x, sum(x[-1]<0), sum(x[-1]>=0 && x[-1]<=10))
```

Comment: it should be `sum` in place of `length`

Comment: thanks :). How can I apply both operations to all but the first field (Client_ID, which is also an integer)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Logical operatos `&&` and `||` work only for scalar and not for vectors contrary to their equivalents `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
> t <- c("client_id", 10, 8, -5, 8, 1, -23, 12) # create vector
> nums <- as.numeric(t[2:length(t)]) # get numbers only from vector
> sum(nums < 0) # Counts the numbers less that 0
[1] 2
> sum(nums > 0 & nums < 10) # counts the number > 0 and < 10
[1] 3
> t <- append(t,sum(nums < 0)) # append to original vector
> t <- append(t,sum(nums > 0 & nums < 10))
> t
 [1] "client_id" "10"        "8"         "-5"        "8"         "1"         "-23"       "12"        "2"         "3"        
>
```